# The file does not exist for the external tool named SWIG

Tags: android, android-ndk, swig

I am trying to build an application using Android NDK. I have followed all the steps and everything works fine and the .so file is being made. But in eclipse when I try to clean the project I get the following error:

```
The file does not exist for the external tool named SWIG.
```

Does anyone have any idea what this might be?

Comment: I have the same problem, but it verified that the external tool exists and continues throwing the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Check Project->Properties->Builders, probably you have an external builder that is not working.